# How to encrypt password in loopback 4?

Tags: strongloop, loopback

```
import { Member } from '../models';
import { MemberRepository} from '../repositories';
import {inject, Context} from '@loopback/context';

export class MemberController {
constructor(
 @repository(MemberRepository) private memberRepository: MemberRepository,
 @Inject('utilities.PasswordHasher') private passwordHasher: PasswordHasher,
    ) { }
}
```

**Getting this error.**

> src/controllers/member.controller.ts:27:65 - error TS2304: Cannot find
>   name 'PasswordHasher'.
>
> 27 @Inject('utilities.PasswordHasher') private passwordHasher:
>   PasswordHasher,
>
> src/controllers/member.controller.ts:27:65 - error TS4063: Parameter
>   'passwordHasher' of constructor from exported class has or is using
>   private name 'PasswordHasher'.
>
> 27 @Inject('utilities.PasswordHasher') private passwordHasher:
>   PasswordHasher,

**Which module can i use for this?.**

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing it like this:

```
import {Entity, model, property} from '@loopback/repository';

const crypto = require('crypto');

@model()
export class User extends Entity{    

  [...]

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: false
  })
  private hashedPassword: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string'
  })
  private salt: string;

  set password(password: string){
    if(!this.salt || !this.salt.length){
      this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
    }
    this.hashedPassword = this.encryptPassword(password);
  }

  private encryptPassword(password: string) {
    return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000, 512, 'sha512').toString('hex');
  };

  public checkPassword(password: string) {
    return this.encryptPassword(password) === this.hashedPassword;
  };
}
```

Comment: could you please also explain how to put this in the controller?  @angelwally

Comment: When you have you create your user entity, when you set your password, it will automatically compute the derived hashed password. If you want to check your user password, you just do myUser->checkPassword("testPassword").